# Open Graph Object Debugger does not match Facebook Share from site

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I am implementing a facebook share button in an angularjs app and after doing all the necessary stuff to get my meta tags updated and read by Facebook's crawler, I am seeing a mismatch between Facebook's debugger tool and what the share dialog shows.

If I run the debugger on my link, I get a successful scrape that pulls all of the meta tag content and shows what the share dialog should look like. Then if I click on the preview to see that actual share dialog, I get a different result as if it is not reading the meta tag content. The same goes for the share button on my actual website.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This might be an issue with protocol inconsistancy. Check you're not using http:// on the debugger, vs https:// on the actual site, and vice versa. Ensure all of your og tags have the correct protocol set, and that the protocol is not omitted.

Answer (score -3):

Facebook provides a javascript SDK where you can specify what data you want to be in your popup. If you want complete control over the dialog then it would probably be best to use FB.ui to do so.

Comment: FB.ui only takes the href parameter, which is just a url. This returns the same result